# Inbrowser image capturing script/engine/solution

Tags: java, ruby, flash

Can you recommend any script/engine for image (with video would be even better) capturing on java, flash or ruby. I've found only [JPEGCam](http://code.google.com/p/jpegcam/) solution, but would be thankful, if you'l recommend any analogues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In flash it is relatively easy. Use this code to capture the webcam, click on the stage and add the bitmap to the stage to see the result. This is the easiest to see the result and to start to play with:

```
var cam:Camera = Camera.getCamera();
var video:Video = new Video(320,240);
video.attachCamera(cam);
addChild(video);

stage.addEventListener("click", mc);

function mc(evt:*):void
{
    //store the bitmap in a BitmapData object
    var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(video.width, video.height, false, 0x00);
    bmd.draw(video);

    //if you want, add it to the stage
    var bmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmd);
    addChild(bmp);
}
```

After this, you can use the `bmd` object according to your project's needs.

Comment: Thing is, that I was hoping to find any ready-to-use solution, because i'm really new to flash.